# Invalid backend model specified

Tags: model, backend

My Magento installation is working as follow:

```
www.mywebsite.com/eu/it/ -> European store, Italian language
www.mywebsite.com/eu/en/ -> European store, English language
www.mywebsite.com/us/en/ -> US store, English language
```

In order to work like this I created in the website root the following paths:

```
/eu/it/
/eu/en/
/us/en/
```

Each one of them has an `index.php` file and an `.htacess` file with a different rewrite base:

```
RewriteBase /eu/it/
RewriteBase /eu/en/
RewriteBase /us/en/
```

Eveything is working fine except for when I try to register / login on the front end. I get the following error:

Invalid backend model specified: `customer/customer_attribute_backend_store`

How can I fix this?

--- UPDATE ---

In the backend of the website when I click on `Customers -> Manage Customers` I get the following error:

AH01797: client denied by server configuration: `/home/svil01/workspace/mywebsite/app/etc/local.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error `Invalid backend model specified: customer/customer_attribute_backend_store` means it can't find that file. Please check if the file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Store.php` exists and is readable.

The second one, `Client denied by server configuration` is actually  a good thing. It's because of a check in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Security.php` that tries to access your `local.xml` which should be prevented.

If you whish to prevent it being logged you can remove the security block by adding the following to the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="notification_survey" />
        <remove name="notification_security" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Although, the security check is there for a reason and I would leave it in there

Comment: The file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Attribute/Backend/Store.php is there but for some strange reason instead of starting with <?php it started with ?php

Thank you very much indeed